# Calculating a value in R to tie the next-highest ranking value

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the following tibble, I'd like to mutate a new column indicating the additional count necessary to tie the next-highest in rank.

```
v <- tribble(
  ~rank, ~name, ~count,
  1, "Mary", 100,
  2, "Fred", 96,
  3, "Sue", 90, 
  3, "Michelle", 90,
  4, "Tom", 72
)
```

I've tried `dplyr`'s lag function (`v %>% mutate(toTie = lag(count) - count)`). This works, but not when there are ties, as any tied observation after the first is compared to an observation with the same value. For example, after the mutate I have this:

```
   rank name     count toTie
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 Mary       100    NA
2     2 Fred        96     4
3     3 Sue         90     6
4     3 Michelle    90     0
5     4 Tom         72    18
```

This output correctly says Sue, who is ranked third, needs 6 to tie Fred, who is second. But because it compares Michelle to Sue (and not Fred), it says Michelle needs none to tie Sue. This is true, but not the intent. Michelle, like Sue, needs 6 to tie second-place Fred.

Any thoughts on a better approach would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the difference on the `lag` of the 'distinct' values of 'count' and do a `right_join`

```
library(dplyr)
v %>%
     distinct(count) %>% 
     mutate(ToTie = lag(count)- count) %>%
     right_join(v) %>%
     select(names(v), ToTie)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#   rank name     count ToTie
#  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 Mary       100    NA
#2     2 Fred        96     4
#3     3 Sue         90     6
#4     3 Michelle    90     6
#5     4 Tom         72    18
```

---

Or another option is `fill`

```
library(tidyr)
v %>%
     mutate(toTie = lag(count) - count, 
            toTie = na_if(toTie, 0)) %>% 
     fill(toTie)
```

Comment: These are very helpful, thank you. I understand the first solution. Had to research the second, as I was unfamiliar with the pattern mutate(x = ..., x = ...). I see now that it is calculating a value then NA'ing the values that are zero. fill() takes care of the rest. Very neat. Thanks again.

Comment: @RDelRossi Thanks.  The first solution is not a general one as it can have some issue when there are multiple duplicates that are not adjacent.  The second one will keep the column as such, while replacing 0 with NA and then replace those NA with the adjacent previous non-NA value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match()` to index the difference at first occurrence.

```
library(dplyr)

v %>%
  mutate(toTie = c(NA, diff(-count))[match(count, count)])

# A tibble: 5 x 4
   rank name     count toTie
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 Mary       100    NA
2     2 Fred        96     4
3     3 Sue         90     6
4     3 Michelle    90     6
5     4 Tom         72    18
```